# Oops! That page can't be found ERROR - WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a hard time with my post here. 
http://www.hautmontravel.com/tips-on-employing-a-search-engine-optimization-expert/

I tried to edit this post at the backend of my WP site and place an image and a youtube video from there however I am getting an "Oops! That page can’t be found."

I checked the plugins, the permalinks and they are working fine.

Is there any idea why is this happening?

Can' seems to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so If I understood this correctly when you make the changes in the WP admin panel and update the post and then when you check the front end you are getting the error ?

Comment: link is working fine.....!!

Comment: @DhavalChheda: exactly. "Oops! That page can’t be found." it says and then the changes made was not made.

Comment: is it just media files that cause this issue or even text update and if just media files then is this happening only for all images and video..you will have to drill down to the core as this issue is unique..